# He collapsed and fell on/to the floor

Tags: prepositions

He collapsed and fell on the floor.

He collapsed and fell to the floor.

Are both possible? What is the difference?

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
the definition/explanation and examples /
grammar rules and examples 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference. For example [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Comment: Both would be understood, but _fell to the floor_ is better, because the person moved _from_ an upright position _to_ the floor.